# How to display customer orders that have been placed

Tags: vb.net

Hi I've got a couple of hours left until a uni project is due.
It's a basic Access database driven e-commerce site. I have a home page, a products page, an orders page, an order confirm page, a shopping cart page and a view current orders page. The site uses an Access database with three tables. A Customer table, with all of the customer details, (FirstName, LastName, EmailAdd, CardNo, CardEx, SortCode, DeliveryAdd, Postcode)

A Products table, with all the product information, (ProductID, ProductName, Price, ProductType, Images, ProductDescription). 
And an Orders table which contains CustomerID and ProductID.
I've managed to get the orders page to work, this leads to the order confirmation page which displays the details the customer just placed.
Here is what I have in the order confirmation page load event so far.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim strDatabaseNameAndLocation As String
    strDatabaseNameAndLocation = Server.MapPath("KingToots.mdb")
    Dim strSQLCommand As String
    strSQLCommand = "SELECT Customer.*, Products.ProductName FROM Customer" & _
        "INNER JOIN Products ON Customer.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID ORDER BY Customer.CustomerID DESC;" 
    Dim objOleDbConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    objOleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & strDatabaseNameAndLocation)
    objOleDbConnection .Open()
    Dim objOleDbCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    objOleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQLCommand, objOleDbConnection)
    Dim objOleDbDataReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    objOleDbDataReader = objOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim datDataTable As System.Data.DataTable
    datDataTable = New System.Data.DataTable()
    datDataTable.Load(objOleDbDataReader)
    gdvOrderdetails.DataSource = datDataTable
    gdvOrderdetails.DataBind()
    objOleDbConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

This returns this error "Syntax error in FROM clause."  I'm guessing my SQL code is wrong.  I noticed when I placed the order in the order page it added an entry in the Access database where the generated CustomerID was 12 on the customers table and 4 in the orders table.  Shouldn't these numbers be the same when they are generated?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your INNER JOIN doesnt look correct. Joining `Products on Customer.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID` ? You are not actually referencing the Orders table in the query.

Comment: Ok so do I need to SELECT everything from the Orders table as well before I use the INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 2):

Add a space here:

```
... Customer**SPACE**" & _
        "INNER...
```

*(Try not to hurt yourself by face palming to hard)*

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm getting "Syntax error in JOIN operation."  What else have I done wrong?

Comment: You appear to be referencing a table in the join that does not exist in the query.

Comment: OK so should I select the orders table as well?  Could the fact that the auto generated number in the CustomerID field being different to the auto generated CustomerID field in the Orders table be a problem?  Surely these need to be the same for the JOIN to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

strSQLCommand = "SELECT Customer.*, Products.ProductName FROM Customer,Products" &_
"INNER JOIN Products ON Customer.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID ORDER BY Customer.CustomerID DESC;"

Comment: Hi there.  Changed to that code and still get the JOIN error.